# Controlling size of QML components from within style property

Tags: qt, qml

I'd like to create my own styled `RadioButton`, but I'm having difficulty controlling the size of the components used in the `RadioButtonStyle` that I am using. I want to put my RadioButton in a `GridLayout` and have the `RadioButton` take up all the available space (as if I were setting `Layout.fillWidth` and `Layout.fillHeight` to `true`)

To start off with, I am using the RadioButtonStyle code from the Qt docs inside a `GridLayout`:

```
GridLayout {

    columns: 3
    anchors.fill: parent

    RadioButton {
        text: "Radio Button"
        style: RadioButtonStyle {
            indicator: Rectangle {

                    implicitWidth: 16
                    implicitHeight: 16

                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        visible: control.checked
                        color: "#555"

                    }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

we can see that `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` of the `indicator` `Rectangle` are set int literals. I want to size the `indicator Rectangle` to fill the space provided by the layout.

I would like the `width` and `height` of the `indicator Rectangle` to track the `width` and `height` of the `RadioButton`, which in turn tracks the `width` and `height` of the `GridLayout` cell containing it.

== UPDATE ==

I have tried the following - setting Layout.maximumHeight/Width prevents Qml going into some kind of infinite loop

```
            RadioButton {

                id: rdbt

                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.maximumWidth: 200
                Layout.maximumHeight: 200




                style: RadioButtonStyle {
                    id: ab

                    indicator: Rectangle {

                        color: "blue"
                        height: control.height
                        width: control.width //control.width
```